# Prevent calling API to get data in a timeframe

Tags: ios, swift, api

I basically have this issue where this Reporting API only allows me to call it once each 90 seconds.

I'm building an app where I get the data each time you open it, to get the latest data, but I somehow need to stop the app from calling the API if it was before 90s wait and show cached data, how can I do this?

Comment: What framework are you using for your API calls?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  It seems pretty straightforward. Keep a record of the last time you called the api and check the elapsed time before you call it again.

Comment: Julien I am using Alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you go to ping the API compare the current time to the last time it was done. Kinda like this:

```
// set defaults for storage
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
// set time 
let date = Date()
//Check Storage
if let theDate = userDefaults.object(forKey: "date") as? Date {
    // on successful load compare times
    if date.timeIntervalSince(theDate) > 90000 /* I think it runs in milliseconds so I put 90 seconds worth there*/ {
        // do API call here
        // save time
        userDefaults.set(date as! Any, forKey: "date")
    } else {
        print("too soon")
} else {
    // data not successfully loaded
    // try to ping API here too
    // save time 
    userDefaults.set(date as! Any, forKey: "date")
}
```